# can't make shortcode working in widget

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a really bad problem...I'm using skeleton wordpress theme as framework to make a child theme.
my child theme work well except for the shortcodes.
if I insert a shortcode in a page everything works fine but, if I insert the same shortcode in a text widget it doesn't work..

I've already tryed to insert in the functions.php this code:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

but nothing change...I've tried also to insert the shortcode directly in my template file
like:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',"[latest excerpt='true' thumbs='true' width='50' height='50' num='5' cat='1']"); ?>
```

can someone tell why any shortcode doesn't work ONLY for me?
Thanks a lot in advance